# Creating a timer

Tags: android, timer, sleep

I'm trying to create a timer, that after the timer ends, will call a function...

For example, I have the function Foo. I want to create a timer, that after 1.5 seconds will call it..

Something like :

```
Timer(Foo(), 2000);
```

I have found this code :

```
    private Handler handler = new Handler(); // Creating new handler
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1500); // Creating a timer for 1.5 seconds
```

and this function :

```
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() 
{
       @Override
       public void run() 
       {
          Foo();

          handler.postDelayed(this, 1500);
       }
    };
```

My problem is, that some times the timer works perfect, usually for the first 2~3 times, and after that, Instead of being a 1.5sec timer, it become something like 0.3sec timer (and the more `handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1500);` is being called, the less time the timer will last (like, wont wait 1.5sec to call Foo, but much less)

Why is that ?
I know that in C++ if I write Console Applications, I can use Sleep.. Maybe I can just do something like this :

```
Sleep(1500);
Foo();
```

Thanks!

Edit: I have answered my own question.

Comment: Is it possible that you have multiple instances creating timers? That is, could one object be creating a timer to be fired 1500 ms, then 300 ms later, another instance creates a similar timer, so you eventually get lots of things firing with short intervals between them?

Comment: Nope. You have to click a button to create the instance of the timer, and I made sure I click each time the button at least5 sec apart (and it's a 1.5sec timer)....

Comment: Can you show that part of the code where you handle button click and create timer?

Comment: I have a button. I got a `onClick` function that relates to the button. then I simply put inside the function   `handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1500);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `Timer` class in Android, and set a repeating timer, with a initial delay.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)
```

A `TimerTask` is very much like a `Runnable`.

See: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: I have used the following code:   
                `Timer timer = new Timer();
         timer.schedule(Foo(), 1500);`
 and the function signature is :
                 `public TimerTask Foo()`

though I get a runtime error, and the application just crashes...

Answer (score 0):

I've used 2 timers :

```
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1500); // Creating a timer for 1.5 seconds
```

this created a 1.5sec timer, while inside the timer loop :

```
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() 
{
   @Override
   public void run() 
   {
      Foo();

      handler.postDelayed(this, 1500);
   }
};
```

I called `handler.postDelayed(this,1500);` again, which made 2 timers -> causing the time bug.